# variable not collecting data from field

Tags: javascript

The code below works ok until the line `document.forms[0]._area.value = dbasedata;` it will only copy the data if the data in that field has been changed AFTER loading the form.
If it is changed to anything (even back to the original value) it will work.
Anyone know why?

```
function dbasetype() {
  var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
  dbasedata2 = dbasedata.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, "");


  if(dbasedata2.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")<0) {
    document.forms[0]._area.value = dbasedata;           
  }  else { setarea(); } 
}
```

**EDIT** I think it may have something to do with it being a dropdown field.

Comment: When is the function being called? Could you be calling it before the page has completely loaded?

Comment: The function is called when the save button is clicked. This function is the first in line before the save is executed. There is no error message it just overwrites the area.value with a blank. It's only a problem in IE. Firefox seems ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding something here, but I think you're missing an else:

```
if(dbasedata2.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")<0) {
    document.forms[0]._area.value = dbasedata;           
  }  { setarea(); }
```

Should be:

```
if(dbasedata2.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")<0) {
    document.forms[0]._area.value = dbasedata;           
} else { 
    setarea(); 
}
```

As it is in your code, `setarea` is always called.  It's hard to say without seeing what `setArea` is, but it would seem like it could be that it is overwriting the value set inside the if.